# How to use mutli-line commands such as here-strings when piping a script?

Tags: powershell, multiline, herestring

When playing with the `-Command -` option of the *PowerShell* executable, I came across the following limitation:

```
Write-Host "SETUP"
Set-PSDebug -Trace 2
Write-Host "TEST ONE"
$foo = "BAR"
Write-Host "TEST TWO"
Get-ChildItem
Write-Host "TEST THREE"
$bar = @"
BAZ
"@
Write-Host "DONE"
```

If I save the previous content to `test.ps1` and execute `cat .\test.ps1 | powershell -Command -`, I get the following output:

```
SETUP
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> Write-Host "TEST ONE"
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
TEST ONE
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> $foo = "BAR"
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
DEBUG:     ! SET $foo = 'BAR'.
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> Write-Host "TEST TWO"
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
TEST TWO
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> Get-ChildItem
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'


    Directory: C:\empty


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       26/02/2017     15:39            179 test.ps1


DEBUG:    1+  >>>> Write-Host "TEST THREE"
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
TEST THREE
```

As you can see, the output from the `Write-Host "DONE"` line never shows.

So, there seems to be something going on for *here strings* when evaluating line by line.  Why is this happening?

And, more importantly, is there a way to make *here strings* work in this context?

Comment: Why are you piping the contents of a script to command? Use `powershell -File test.ps1`

Comment: I'm trying to bootstrap a powershell script from Windows Scripting Host by using a single file, without the need to create a temporary file.  There are a lot of details involved and I have a workaround for this limitation, but I'm still curious about why here-strings are not supported in this situation.

Comment: It seems that problem not with here-strings, but with multiline commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: The following applies as of Windows PowerShell v5.1.14393.693 and PowerShell Core v6.0.0-alpha16.</sup>

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as he often does, provides the crucial pointer in a comment on the question (and later, via comments, also provided the simplest fix):

> It seems that the problem is not with here-strings [per se], but with multiline commands [in general].

**`-Command -` requires *at least 1 empty line after* the *last multi-line command*** in the input for all commands to be recognized properly.

A here-string is by definition an instance of a multi-line command, which is why you've experienced the problem.

Therefore, to **work around the problem in scripts that contain multi-line commands, insert *a single empty line* at the *end*:**

```
Write-Host "SETUP"
Set-PSDebug -Trace 2
Write-Host "TEST ONE"
$foo = "BAR"
Write-Host "TEST TWO"
Get-ChildItem
Write-Host "TEST THREE"
$bar = @"
BAZ
"@
Write-Host "DONE"  # IMPORTANT: Note the empty line below.
```

---

#### Why is this necessary?

The answer can be found in powershell's own CLI help (`powershell -?`), whose **description of the `-Command` parameter** starts with (emphasis added):

> Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) **as though they were
> typed at the Windows PowerShell command prompt**

***Without the `PSReadLine` module loaded*, when you type a *multi-line* command *interactively*, you need an *extra* <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke to submit the entry**, so as to let PowerShell know when you're done entering the command.

<sup>Note: The `PSReadLine` module, which became a standard part of *interactive* PowerShell sessions in W10/PSv5, thankfully *obviates* the need for this extra keystroke, because it *infers* from the syntax of what's been entered whether the command is complete.

However, `PSReadLine` is *not* involved when you pass commands via `-Command -`.

If you want to experience how PowerShell *itself* parses multi-line commands in an interactive session, execute `Remove-Module PSReadLine` first.</sup>

**Unfortunately, the same logic is applied when `-Command -` is used to provide the commands via *stdin***, so **you must simulate the extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke with an *empty line* in your input**, although PetSerAl figured out that a *single* empty line *at the very end* is enough.

---

If you'd like to see this behavior changed and/or want proper support for `-File -` to treat the input like a *script*, consider making your voice heard in [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223).

Comment: Just brilliant!  Thank you very much