# powershell stdin pipes and redirection

Tags: bash, powershell, pipe, cross-platform

Hello so I have been making a small cross platform script I can curl and pipe into bash and Powershell. The basic idea is the server sends a command to the interpreter and then it gives a command to redirect all output after to stdout. An example in bash is

```
#some commands 
aplay rick.wav
cat -
random text
that will be redirected to stdout by cat... 
bash will never see this
```

I would then pipe this to stdin of bash

But for Powershell I can do `cat test.ps1 | iex` or `cat test.ps1 | powershell -`
But can't redirect stdin to stdout continuously in one command like `cat -` because cat doesn't look from stdin.

Also some side notes after trying a lot of random things it seems like there are many stdin types for Windows, one being keyboard and another being pipes

Comment: As an aside: Windows doesn't come with a `cat` executable, and in PowerShell `cat` is simply an _alias_ for the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), which doesn't accept pipeline input.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe lines of text to `powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), via `-Command -` (`-c -`), and it will interpret them one by one.

Here's an **interactive demonstration from *inside* PowerShell**; it works the same with input piped (provided via stdin) from the outside:

```
# Repeatedly prompt for a line of input and execute it as a PowerShell command.
# Press Ctrl-C to exit.
& { while ($true) { Read-Host } } | powershell -noprofile -c -
```

Note:

- `-Command -` has problematic aspects, notably with commands that *span multiple lines* (an *additional* <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke / newline is then needed for the command to be recognized) and so does `-File -`, whose behavior is even stranger - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475326/45375) and [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223).

---

**Another demonstration, simulating *outside* stdin input** via 2 lines piped to `powershell -c -`:

```
'get-date', 'get-item /' | powershell -noprofile -c -
```

The two commands are executed and their output is printed; `powershell.exe` then exits, because no more stdin input is available; however, with indefinite stdin input (analogous to `cat -` on Unix-like platforms) the PowerShell process would be kept alive indefintely too.

Comment: Ah this does work but if I run `cat program.ps1 | iex` it requests from keyboard not from the rest of stdin

Comment: @JesseTaube, yes, `Read-Host` doesn't read from stdin (unless the script is called via PowerShell's CLI). If you want to provide stdin input from the outside, omit the `Read-Host` loop, which was only meant to _simulate_ indefinite stdin input. Please see my update. If that doesn't help, you need to clarify your use case.